# Find the lowest white pixel

Tags: matlab, image-processing, binary-image

I have this binary image.[image]

How do i find the coordinate of the lowest white pixel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in your matrix you have 0 and 1 values representing white and black

you can find white pixels with

```
   [row,col,v] = find(A);
```

Then the lowest pixel has coordinates

```
x = max(row) 
y = col(find(row==max(row)))
```

If you have more than one lowest pixel maybe you can simply take the coordinates of one of them. For example:

```
mrow = max(row);

y = col(find(row==mrow(1)))%if you wanna take the lowest pixel on the left
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm new to matlab.I got this error `Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [`. I tried to assign x and y coordinates to variables. The x coordinate works but y coordinate `coorY = col(find(row==max(row)))` gives me more than one value.

Comment: The first error is syntactic, verify the parenthesis. Note that I wrote the coordinates in a mathematical fashion that is not a valid Matlab syntax. The second error means that there is not a single lowest white pixel. I guess that you can simply take only one of them. I'll try to edit the answer with a simple solution.